# Accessing a random number from a 3d numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a array object self.transition[s_dyna,a_dyna,:] where the shape itself is 100,4,100.

I would like to get a random number from the last dimension, denoted by [:] and passed it to a variable s_prime. Is there anyway I can do that in numpy?

Answer (score 0):

I am using an array of dummy data to mimic your (100,4,100) shape array with `rand = np.random.rand(100,4,100)`. You can then generate random numbers between `0` and `99` before plugging them into a slicing method.

```
import numpy as np

rand = np.random.rand(100,4,100)
idx = np.random.randint(0,99) # Generates a random index to reference
print(rand[:,:,idx])  # Gives an array from the last dimension

s_prime = rand[:,:,idx] # Plug this single random int into the 
                        # index you want to reference
```

If you only want a single number, you need to slice all axes using a similar method, then you can get

```
import numpy as np

rand = np.random.rand(100,4,100)
idx = np.random.randint(0,99)
jdx = np.random.randint(0,3)
kdx = np.random.randint(0,99)
print(rand[kdx,jdx,idx]) 

s_prime = rand[kdx,jdx,idx] # Gives single random number
```